# Calling MSSQL stored proc from php

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

We have been stumped with this all morning.

I have an MSSQL stored proc which processes some records. Each record generates an email with dynamic content, and this is populated from another stored proc.

So the first stored proc has a cursor, and each row is processed resulting in a call to another stored proc, which itself has a cursor to loop through. The first stored proc has no output parameters or returned values, etc, while the second uses output parameters to return fields to the first proc.

This works fine from Datagrip.

Calling this from php using PDO (or using other drivers) it fails to run fully. It would produce a small batch of records then stop (tends to be either 5, 9, 13 or 45 - has changed as we have experimented with difference solutions).

We have managed to get it to run now using PDOStatement::nextRowset . We use a query of the first stored proc and then using `while ( $stmt->nextRowset() ) ;`  to loop through the (non existent / unwanted) row sets.

This works. But as the first stored proc isn't returning anything (just that pdo seems to want to process some kind of internal result set) this seems very dirty and inefficient.

**Is there an alternative? Possibly a parameter to pass to pdo, or a setting within the stored proc?**

Below there is some simplified code to show how things interact.

PHP calling script.

```
<?php
$emailRepository = new EmailRepository(hostname, port, dbname, username, password);

$ret = $emailRepository->sendRenewalEmails();

class EmailRepository
{

    public function __construct($hostname, $port, $dbname, $username, $password)
    {
        $this->hostname = $hostname;
        $this->port = $port;
        $this->dbname = $dbname;
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->password = $password;
        $this->connect();
    }

    private function connect()
    {
        try {
            $this->db = new PDO ("sqlsrv:Server=$this->hostname,$this->port;Database=$this->dbname", $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            var_dump("Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function sendRenewalEmails()
    {
      try {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("EXEC membership_queue_renewal_emails");
        $stmt->execute();
        do {
          echo '>';
        } while($stmt->nextRowset());
        return true;
      } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
      }
    }
}
```

First stored proc (heavily cut down)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[queue_renewal_emails]
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @curr_member_cursor     CURSOR;
    DECLARE @curr_club_cursor       CURSOR;
    DECLARE @g_personid             INT;

    DECLARE @g_emailTemplateId      INT;
    DECLARE @g_email_subject        VARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @g_email_html           VARCHAR(max);
    DECLARE @g_email_plain          VARCHAR(max);

    DECLARE @g_personEmail          VARCHAR(128);

    SET @curr_club_cursor = CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            bgemailTemplate.bgemte_name,
            bgemailTemplate.bgemte_emailtemplateid,
            vpersonpe.pers_emailaddress,
            vpersonpe.pers_personId,
    FROM  company               WITH(NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN complink             WITH(NOLOCK)    ON complink.clli_companyid = complink.Comp_CompanyId
    AND complink.clli_Deleted is null
    INNER JOIN vpersonpe            WITH(NOLOCK)    ON vpersonpe.pers_personId = complink.clli_personId
    INNER JOIN bgemailTemplate      WITH(NOLOCK)    ON bgemailTemplate.bgemte_Deleted IS NULL
    WHERE vPersonPE.pers_deleted                    IS NULL
    AND   company.comp_deleted                      IS NULL
    AND   vPersonPE.pers_parentid                   IS NULL
    AND   vpersonpe.pers_status                     NOT IN ('Cancelled','Expired','Suspended','Awaiting Approval','Declined','On hold','Revoked','Expelled');

    -- loop through each course
    OPEN @curr_club_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @curr_club_cursor INTO @g_email_subject, @g_emailTemplateId, @g_personEmail, @g_personid;
    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC dbo.populateEmail @g_emailtemplateid   /* Email template id */,
                                @g_email_plain OUTPUT /* Plain text email to have the placeholders replaced */,
                                @g_email_subject OUTPUT,
                                @g_personid ;
        FETCH NEXT FROM @curr_club_cursor INTO @g_email_subject, @g_emailTemplateId, @g_personEmail, @g_personid;
    END
    CLOSE @curr_club_cursor
    DEALLOCATE @curr_club_cursor

END
go
```

Second stored proc (heavily cut down).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[populateEmail]
    @p_emailtemplateid          INT,
    @p_email_text               VARCHAR(max) OUTPUT,
    @p_email_subject            VARCHAR(200) OUTPUT,
    @p_person_id                INT
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- CURSORs
    DECLARE @curr_field_cursor                  CURSOR;
    DECLARE @g_email_plain                      VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @g_email_subject                    VARCHAR(200) = '';

    DECLARE @g_emte_emailtemplateid             INT;
    DECLARE @g_EmailPlaceholderId               INT;
    DECLARE @g_place_holder                     VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @g_source_column                    VARCHAR(128);
    DECLARE @g_prev_source_query_num            INT;
    DECLARE @g_source_query_num                 INT;

    -- Variables to read results into from each query
    DECLARE @g_q11_comp_name                    VARCHAR(180);
    DECLARE @g_q11_comp_website                 VARCHAR(300);
    DECLARE @g_q11_comp_pers_salutation         VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE @g_q11_comp_pers_firstname          VARCHAR(90);
    DECLARE @g_q11_comp_pers_lastname           VARCHAR(120);
    -- Start processing

    SET @p_email_text = '';

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    SET @curr_field_cursor = CURSOR
    LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
    FOR
    SELECT a.emte_emailtemplateid,
            b.emtl_EmailPlaceholderId,
            c.empl_PlaceHolder,
            c.empl_SourceQueryNum,
            c.empl_SourceColumn,
            a.emte_plaintextemail,
            a.emte_subject
    FROM EmailTemplate a with (nolock)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  EmailTemplateLink b with (nolock)
    ON a.emte_emailtemplateid = b.emtl_EmailTemplateId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  EmailPlaceholder c with (nolock)
    ON b.emtl_EmailPlaceholderId = c.empl_EmailPlaceholderID
    WHERE a.emte_emailtemplateid = @p_emailtemplateid
    ORDER BY c.empl_SourceQueryNum;

    -- Loop through each required place holder for the passed email template.

    SET @g_prev_source_query_num = 0;

    OPEN @curr_field_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @curr_field_cursor INTO @g_emte_emailtemplateid, @g_EmailPlaceholderId, @g_place_holder, @g_source_query_num, @g_source_column, @g_email_plain, @g_email_subject;
    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN

        IF @g_prev_source_query_num = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @p_email_text = @g_email_plain;
            SET @p_email_subject = @g_email_subject;
        END;

        IF @g_source_query_num = 11
        BEGIN
            IF @g_prev_source_query_num != @g_source_query_num
            BEGIN
                SELECT @g_q11_comp_name = comp_name,
                        @g_q11_comp_website = comp_website,
                        @g_q11_comp_pers_salutation = Pers_Salutation,
                        @g_q11_comp_pers_firstname = pers_firstname,
                        @g_q11_comp_pers_lastname = pers_lastname
                FROM company with (nolock)
                LEFT OUTER JOIN vPerson with (nolock) ON company.Comp_PrimaryPersonId = vPerson.Pers_PersonId
                LEFT OUTER JOIN address with (nolock) ON company.Comp_PrimaryAddressId = address.Addr_AddressId
                WHERE company.Comp_CompanyId        = @p_person_id;
            END;

            IF @g_source_column = 'comp_name'
            BEGIN
                SET @p_email_text       = REPLACE(@p_email_text, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_name, ''));
                SET @p_email_subject    = REPLACE(@p_email_subject, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_name, ''));
            END;
            ELSE IF @g_source_column = 'comp_website'
            BEGIN
                SET @p_email_text       = REPLACE(@p_email_text, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_website, ''));
                SET @p_email_subject    = REPLACE(@p_email_subject, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_website, ''));
            END;
            ELSE IF @g_source_column = 'comp_primary_person_firstname'
            BEGIN
                SET @p_email_text       = REPLACE(@p_email_text, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_pers_salutation, ''));
                SET @p_email_subject    = REPLACE(@p_email_subject, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_pers_salutation, ''));
            END;
            ELSE IF @g_source_column = 'comp_primary_person_salutation'
            BEGIN
                SET @p_email_text       = REPLACE(@p_email_text, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_pers_firstname, ''));
                SET @p_email_subject    = REPLACE(@p_email_subject, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_pers_firstname, ''));
            END;
            ELSE IF @g_source_column = 'comp_primary_person_lastname'
            BEGIN
                SET @p_email_text       = REPLACE(@p_email_text, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_pers_lastname, ''));
                SET @p_email_subject    = REPLACE(@p_email_subject, @g_place_holder, COALESCE(@g_q11_comp_pers_lastname, ''));
            END;
        END;

        SET @g_prev_source_query_num = @g_source_query_num;
        FETCH NEXT FROM @curr_field_cursor INTO @g_emte_emailtemplateid, @g_EmailPlaceholderId, @g_place_holder, @g_source_query_num, @g_source_column, @g_email_plain, @g_email_subject;
    END;

    CLOSE @curr_field_cursor
    DEALLOCATE @curr_field_cursor

END
go
```

Comment: Why are you using NOLOCK on every single table AND using the read uncommitted isolation level? This is redundant. But using the NOLOCK hint everywhere is rarely a good idea. It does fun things like randomly return missing and/or duplicate rows in addition to whole mess of other awesome things. https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere

Comment: @SeanLange - desperate times! This is example code, but the source tables are relatively static, and this process is very much secondary to any updates to these tables.

Comment: If the data is static then splattering NOLOCK hints all over the place is useless anyway as there wouldn't be any locking to ignore. ;)

Comment: @SeanLange, it isn't static, just not constantly changing. And these procs must have zero impact on any of these updates (if the data is a moment out of date then that doesn't matter for this process).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> as the first stored proc isn't returning anything ... is there an alternative to `while ( $stmt->nextRowset() ) ;`

I'ts probably the rowcount messages causing the client to see empty rowsets.  Add `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first line of each stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you. I had just tried the same as you replied (I had SET NOCOUNT ON in the secondary procs). Setting this in the primary proc has fixed it.